# Trying to run a simple API GET request for private Gitlab account

Tags: gitlab, api, powershell

I am trying to run a simple API request to GitLab through powershell 5.1. After generating an access token with all privileges using the Web UI I tried to run the following:

`invoke-restmethod https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=<my_private_token>/<project_id>`

Unfortunately, I get an error:

```
invoke-restmethod : {"message":"401 Unauthorized"}
At line:1 char:13
+ $response = invoke-restmethod https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?priv
...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebReques
   t:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.Pow
   erShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Why am I getting 401 error when I try to access project related information?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter should come at the end of the URL:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234567?private_token=$my_private_token
```

I prefer to pass the token in the header:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{ 'PRIVATE-TOKEN'=$_my_private_token } -Uri http://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234567
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#personalproject-access-tokens